# Android fail retrofit http call in deep sleep mode

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have a **galaxy tabA tablet on Android 7.0** and I use **Retrofit 2** to send http call to my server every 15 minutes to log information about the tablet. My tablet enter in "**deep sleep**" mode when it is not charging for more than 5 minutes with screen off.
During this deep sleep mode, none of my calls can reach my server and I receive a "connection timeout error".

Does someone has a better understanding of "**deep sleep**" mode and explain here what is the best way to achieve my behavior (send logs every 15 minutes h24/24) ?

Can someone explain if it is a retrofit bug or an Android feature or something else ?

Comment: is the requirement for every 15 min really important? Is the data you send really useful even when the tablet is not in use?

Comment: you should probably read this https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you must use evernote library : https://github.com/evernote/android-job

**In fact, "doze mode" block access to network in deep sleep and wake up at periodic time to let network access open.**
This library helped me catch those holy periodic window with network to send my server logs.

Just follow the tutorial in readme to configure this feature.

Comment: Thank you, your post helped me to find WorkManager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Answer (score 0):

*I think you should read about this*

**Doze Mode** **Starting from Android 6.0 (API level 23)**

> If a user leaves a device unplugged and stationary for a period of
>   time, with the screen off, the device enters Doze mode. In Doze mode,
>   the system attempts to conserve battery by restricting apps' access to
>   network and CPU-intensive services. It also prevents apps from
>   accessing the network and defers their jobs, syncs, and standard
>   alarms.
>
> Periodically, the system exits Doze for a brief time to let apps
>   complete their deferred activities. During this maintenance window,
>   the system runs all pending syncs, jobs, and alarms, and lets apps
>   access the network.

For more info read this:
[Optimizing for Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

so you need to wake up your phone when you need to perform your task like sending notification or some...

Comment: Best practice IS NOT to wake up your phone any time you need to do something. 
The best practice is to wait for the phone periodic exit of doze mode AND THEN execute all your work during that small amount of time for best battery consumption.

That is what android jobs are for, cf : https://github.com/evernote/android-job